# ESP32-S3 USB Serial is read-only

Tags: usb, serial, esp32

I have a ESP32-S3-DevKitC-1 board. It has two USB ports, one connected to a USB to UART chip (brigde), the other connected to SoC directly (USB Serial).

The USB Serial is much faster than bridge for flashing and also can be used for JTAG debugging. However, there is a problem...

I tried `blink` and [matter/light](https://github.com/espressif/esp-matter/tree/main/examples/light) examples, the first one only outputs to serial but second one also reads commands from serial. In both of them, I cannot send (write) anything to serial port if the board is connected using USB Serial. IDF-Monitor says this:

> Writing to serial is timing out. Please make sure that your application supports an interactive console and that you have picked the correct console for serial communication.

PuTTY doesn't send anything also. Both only show device outputs.

If I use the bridge, both read and write are OK.

I'm using linux and my user is already member of `dialout` and `plugdev` groups.
Flashing program using USB Serial is OK also which means it can write while flashing.
If I boot device in bootloader (Firmware download) mode, IDF-Monitor doesn't show timeout warning which means it can write to the port.

So why I cannot send data to USB Serial while running application?